# show that $\operatorname{ch}(t) \leq e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$

Tags: inequality, power-series

let $t$ be a real number .

show that : 
$\operatorname{cosh}(t) \leq e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$

it was imposed to use power series of the two functions to show it .

I have for each real $t$ :

$\operatorname{cosh}(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ t^{2n}}{(2n)!}$

$e^{ \frac{t^2}{2}}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ t^{2n}}{2^nn!}$

1- what am I supposed to remark ?

2- In general , is using power series a good method to show inequalities ?

Edit:

as a hint given to me :

I ll show that:

$(2n)! \leq 2^n n$

using recurrence i have $(2(n+1))!=(2n)!(2n+1)(2n+2) \leq 2^n n(2n+1)(2n+2) \leq  2^{n+1} (n+0,5)(n+1) \leq 2^{n+1}(n+1)$

Comment: Can you show that $(2n)!\ge 2^n n!$?

Comment: What is $\mathrm{ch}$?

Comment: @enedil hyperbolic cos

Comment: This is more commonly written $\color{blue}{\cosh}$, I think.

Comment: Note $2^n\,n!=(2n)!!$.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that
$$\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}\leq e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$$ or $f(t)\geq0,$ where
$$f(t)=\frac{t^2}{2}+t+\ln2-\ln(e^{2t}+1).$$
But $$f''(t)=\left(\frac{e^{2t}-1}{e^{2t}+1}\right)^2\geq0,$$ which says that $f'$ increases.

Also, $$f'(t)=t+1-\frac{2e^{2t}}{e^{2t}+1},$$ which gives $f'(0)=0$ and for $t=0$ $f$ gets a minimal value.

Id est, $$f(t)\geq f(0)=0$$ and we are done!

Also, you can use that $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and $f''(t)\geq0$ for all real $t$ and $f''(\theta)\geq0.$